# What the limit of a matrix over time shows about the future

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$x_k$ is the fraction of people who prefer cake to pie at year $k$. The remaining fraction $y_k=1-x_k$ prefer pie. At year $k+1$, $\frac{1}{5}$ of those who prefer cake change their mind. Also at year $k+1$, $\frac{1}{10}$ of those who prefer pie change their mind.

a. Create the matrix $A$ to give $\begin{pmatrix}x_{k+1} \\y_{k+1}\end{pmatrix} =A\begin{pmatrix}x_k \\y_k\end{pmatrix}$ and find the limit of $A^k\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ as $k\to\infty$

I got this part I think. $A=\begin{pmatrix}.8 & .1 \\.2 & .9\end{pmatrix}$. I ended up getting $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3} \\\frac{2}{3}\end{pmatrix}$ as my answer using eigenvalues and eigenvectors and then using diagonalization to solve it.

b. **Over the long term, how will the people's preferences be split between cake and pie? Explain your reasoning**

I'm not sure how to answer this part though. Any tips you could give me based on my answer to part a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to find the $A^{\infty} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} A^n$ and see what happens when you apply it to arbitrary "distribution" of pie and cake lovers. However, check your eigenvalues: this matrix clearly has one eigenvalue equal to 1 (I vaguely recall, but I'm not sure that all matrices which columns sum to 1 have this eigenvalue).